# Can anyone explain me this?

Tags: c++, pointers, floating-point

```
#include<iostream>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(){
      float **A;
      int m,n;

}
```

This program is incomplete . I just want to know what's the meaning and use of `float **A` . Can anyone tell me.

Comment: What is your level of understanding? Would you know the meaning of `float *A`?

Comment: [See here.](https://cdecl.org/?q=float+**A%3B)

Comment: @JaMiT The meaning of this from my understanding is that we are declaring an float type pointer A .

Comment: @AshKetch Well, "pointer to float" is a better phrasing than "float type pointer". From here, it should not be too big a leap to read `float **A` as `(float *) *A`, a pointer to [a pointer to float] called `A`. I'll leave the rest to the linked duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It is a pointer to a pointer. As Ali said, it is just like simulating a two-dimensional array.
[image]

Comment: No, no. At best, a *pointer-to-pointer* can *simulate* a two dimensional array, but a *pointer-to-pointer* has nothing to do with an array at all. Full stop.